# Cannot access 1 of 2 providers inside subfunction in angularjs service

Tags: angularjs, service, closures, factory

I have this code (simplified):

```
angular
  .module('app.core')
  .factory('experienceDataservice', ['$http', 'Facebook', dataservice]);

  function dataservice($http, Facebook){
    var service = {
      getExperiences: getExperiences
    };
    debugger;
      function getExperiences() {
       debugger;
     }
   }
```

And the problem is that at the first `debugger;`, within the `dataservice` block I can access both `$http` and `Facebook` but at the second `debugger;`, within the `getExperiences` block I can only access `$http` and not `Facebook`.

I do not understand why this happens.
I tried to keep the code as simple as possible.
If more details are needed ask and I will provide.

Larger snippet:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular
  .module('app.core')
  .factory('experienceDataservice', ['$http', 'Facebook', dataservice]);

  function dataservice($http, Facebook){
    var service = {
      getExperiences: getExperiences
    };
    debugger;
      function getExperiences() {
       debugger;
       var access = '';
       var access = Facebook.getAccessToken(); //Does not work
       var auth = 'Bearer' + access; 

    var req = 
    {
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/reviews?location=London&term=',
      headers: 
        {
          'Accept' : "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",
          'Authorization': auth
        }
    }
    $http(req) // Does 'work'
         .success(function(data, status, headers, config){debugger;})
         .error(function(data, status, headers, config){debugger;});

     }
    return service;
   }
})();
```

Comment: That code should work, can you post a larger snippet?

Comment: sure, added the entire file

Comment: On the line `Facebook.getAccessToken()` I'm assuming it's giving you some sort of error that something is undefined. Is it `Facebook` or `gateAccessToken()`? Basically, what happens when you do `console.log(Facebook)`?

Comment: I tried `console.log(Facebook)` and that does not give an undefined error. But returns an object that doesn't have the getAccessToken() function so I think you found the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [Ben Black](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1703505/ben-black) pointed out in the comments on the question, I was calling a non-existant function by confusing `Facebook` and another global in my code.